# How can i make bigger rectangles in a tree in LaTeX

Tags: forest

I'm trying to insert a vector inside of a node in a tree,but the vector is too big and i don't know how to set bigger rectangles, so the vector can fit.
For example, in the below code i tried to insert (3,4,2,2)  in one node, but all i can get is (3.

Here's the output:
[image: Output]

```
\begin{forest}

for tree={
    grow=south,
   rectangle, draw,rounded corners, align=center, minimum size=4ex, inner sep=10pt,
    s sep=10mm
        }

  [IP

    [(3,4,2,2) [2] ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

Comment: `,` is used as a separator for the options. Use `[{(3,4,2,2)} [2]]`. (Better would be `[{(3,4,2,2)}, math content [2]]`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering @Qrrbrbirlbel comment an MWE for your tree can be:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree={
   draw, rounded corners, minimum size=4ex, inner sep=10pt, % <---
if level = 0{}{math content},   % <---
   grow=south,
   l sep = 4mm,                 % <---
        }
[IP
    [{(3,4,2,2)}                % <--- see @Qrrbrbirlbel comment
        [2] 
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Changes in MWE are in comparison to your code fragment marked by `% <---`

[image]